# View's position is changed while adding a child view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have two views side by side(left & right).At one time i am just showing one view other view not visible because i have moved that view out of scene towards the right of screen.I have set the x position in such a way so that it is not visible(view is always to the right of screen so not visible).So i press next button which is near to first view then my second view is visible & first view is hidden. I have used animation to slide thew view from left to right & right to left.

```
-(void)handleSingleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"first");
    CGFloat screenWidth = 0.0;
    if(IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
         screenWidth=self.view.frame.size.width-120.0;
    }
    if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        screenWidth=self.view.frame.size.width-68.0;

    }
    NSLog(@"New screen width is %f",screenWidth);
    [self.back_view setHidden:false];
    [self.front_view setHidden:true];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.front_view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.front_view.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0);
        self.back_view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.back_view.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0);
    }];
}
-(void)handleSingleTapGesture_one:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    CGFloat screenWidth = 0.0;
    if(IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        screenWidth=self.view.frame.size.width-120.0;

    }
    if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        screenWidth=self.view.frame.size.width-68.0;

    }
     NSLog(@"New screen width is %f",screenWidth);
    [self.back_view setHidden:true];
    [self.front_view setHidden:false];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.front_view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.front_view.frame, screenWidth, 0.0);
        self.back_view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.back_view.frame, screenWidth, 0.0);
    }];
}
```

On the `backView` i have added a subview on `bottom-right` so when ever i try to add the view inside that view then then main view is shifted to the right i don't know why.Please tell me how can i get the solution?

Comment: Comment: You don't have to animate a hidden view's position.

Comment: can you provide the screen shot of your final view (when this problem occurred).

Comment: can't share the UI sorry

Comment: i tried but that does make any diffrence.@meaning-matters

Comment: Can you add the code in which you add the subview to `backView`?